# Proxy authentication for Azure CLI

Tags: azure, authentication, proxy, command-line-interface, kerberos

For the Azure CLI, is there a way to use proxy authentication? Our proxy servers needs all requests to be authenticated and I do not see any document relating. Using HTTP_PROXY environment variable, I can instruct the az cli to use a particular proxy server but I cannot define it to use proxy authentication, OR if there is a way to do this, I do not know. Our Proxy authentication has to be done either through NTLM or Kerberos.

Can the relevant team, please check If we can configure az cli to use Kerberos proxy authentication?

Comment: Please refer to [ask].  Explain how you researched the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.  Only after that point will people be more willing to help.

Comment: Azure CLI uses Python, & it supports Basic Http Auth behind a proxy for the  request. The documentation shows no evidence of Kerberos  auth support,  layered along with the request. Python lib allows named requests, whose pass-through proxy can be configured by environment variables. Doc mentions HTTP basic auth only, and not Kerberos. When I find the answer myself or from someone who is knowledgeable I will post here, so it benefits others and they don't get downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the answer lies in the fact that Azure CLI is built on top of Python. Now as regards Authentication, Azure CLI uses AAD based protocol, which is handled by the ADAL library for Python whose source code is [published here.](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python)

So if this is of interest and someone wanted to see the wire level details, please dig in here.

As mentioned Azure CLI is built on TOP of python, one of the reasons being to give it a broad cross-platform reach, as it available across Windows, Mac, Linux (and may be other ports are available).

And ADAL Python is based on a popular Python HTTP library. While the proxy can be configured (and that is **not** the question here), what was asked and what enterprises want is a way to use Kerberos/NTLM to authenticate the requests while funneling it through a proxy. So if you dig into the documents for the Python HTTP library, [you can see named requests, whose proxy support can be configured inline or by environment vars](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) (again that is **not** the ASK).

Now when you dig into authentication when requests are being proxied, the document mentions HTTP basic auth only, and there is no mention of Kerberos/NTLM type of authentication. Now **if** one has worked with any security conscious enterprise, this would be difficult to get an exception. This has been requested by some enterprises, where they want to authenticate (security requirement) all Azure CLI requests at their external facing proxies before it leaves the perimeter.

The current answer is there is not a supported way to do this, unless an auth handler is implemented that does this, for the scenario where a proxy is in place. This is a request that would squarely belong to the Python HTTP library owners, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for the answer to this question the answer can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-configure-proxy?tabs=bash)

> ```
> # Non-authenticated HTTP server:
> HTTP_PROXY=http://10.10.1.10:1180
>
> # Authenticated HTTP server:
> HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@10.10.1.10:1180
>
> # Non-authenticated HTTPS server:
> HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.10.1.10:1180
>
> # Authenticated HTTPS server:
> HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@10.10.1.10:1180
> ```

Obviously not the most secure approach and be careful to url encode any special characters.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove protocol "http|https" from variable string

```
# Non-authenticated HTTP server:
HTTP_PROXY=server.fqdn.int:8080

# Non-authenticated HTTPS server:
HTTPS_PROXY=server.fqdn.int:8080
```